# How to toggle bluetooth using androidviewclient

Tags: android, monkeyrunner, androidviewclient

I am trying to toggle Bluetooth using AndroidviewClient. Below is part of the code. I am able to "find Bluetooth" and get the id and text also. Then I want to get get the view for ON/OFF to toggle. When I print in the below for loop, I get 3 views and one of them is the view for ON or OFF based on the current state. How to check in the for loop for this view to toggle it?
Thanks for your help,

BR
Srini

```
view = vc.findViewWithText('Bluetooth')
print "Bluetooth id :", view.getId()
print "Blutooth Text    :", view.getText()

for i in view.parent.parent.children:
    print str(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to get the '**Bluetooth**' View grandparent and then search for the ToggleButton in that subtree.
To find the View in this case we use the pattern '**ON|OFF**', so it doesn't matter the state as toggling it is our objective:

```
parent = vc.findViewWithTextOrRaise('Bluetooth').getParent().getParent()
vc.findViewWithTextOrRaise(re.compile('ON|OFF'), root=parent).touch()
```

This is probably the best solution. However there is an alternative that may also suit your needs and it's much easier to obtain.

Run **[culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/culebra)** to generate a script template:

```
$ culebra -i off -t on -d on -C -j on -o ~/tmp/bluetooth.py
```

then, you see in the script something like (may vary depending on the API level and device):

```
# class=android.widget.TextView text="Bluetooth"
no_id26 = vc.findViewWithTextOrRaise('Bluetooth')

# class=android.widget.Switch text="OFF"
no_id27 = vc.findViewWithTextOrRaise('OFF')
```

so, if you just append

```
no_id27.touch()
```

to the script it will toggle **Bluetooth** every time you run it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I haven't tried Culebra but the first sudggestion works great.